# android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size while sending email with large body

Tags: java, android

I need to send email with large body in my Android application. 
I have got **android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size** exception while using **Intent.ACTION_SENDTO** with large **Intent.EXTRA_TEXT** when I start activity basically like this for this intent:

```
    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts(mailto, "", null));
    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "name");

    String body = here I have a large text string//

    emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
    startActivity(emailIntent);
```

Could somebody please tell me the way how to create mail with large body?

Comment: Move much of the body into an attachment and use `EXTRA_STREAM` for that.

Comment: Is it the only way? Is it possible some how create email with large text in body?

Comment: Set up a Web service. Call your Web service with the details of the email. Have your Web service send the email on your behalf.